# How to add an element with attributes into an existing Xelement?

Tags: xml, vb.net, xelement

Hello I want to dynamically add  the branch element which you can see in the XML code down 1 to N times to the code. This will depend on the numbers of branches the company is in.

```
<branch key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "branch") %>/>
```

But I did not find out yet how to add an element which looks like this

```
<branch/>
```

I only found ways to add elements like  this :

```
<branch></branch>
```

My Plan was to add the branch elements first and after that the Attributes.  But If i can create both in one operation, its also good^^

Cheers Steven

```
<address
        firstname=<%= attributecheck(xml, "firstname") %>
        lastname2=<%= attributecheck(xml, "lastname2") %>
        lastname=<%= attributecheck(xml, "lastname") %>>
    <function key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "function") %>/>
    <position key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "position") %>/>
    <saluation key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "saluation") %>/>
    <nameaddition key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "nameaddition") %>/>
    <acadtitle key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "acadititle") %>/>
    <departmentcode key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "departmentcode") %>/>
    <language key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "langauge") %>/>
    <branch key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "branch") %>/>
    <country key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "country") %>/>
    <addresssource key=<%= propertycheck(xml, "addresssource") %>/>
    <addresslock key=""/>
</address>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the problem. The following code outputs the branch element as you want:

```
Dim k As String = Nothing
Dim x = <address><branch key=<%= k %>/></address>
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString())
```

Output is:

```
<address>
  <branch />
</address>
```